# Cluster points of a sequence $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that there is a sequence $a_n$ with the below subsequnces:

a) $a_n = \frac{n+2+1}{n^2 + n + 1}$ when $n$ is odd.

b) $a_n = \frac{sinn}{n}$ when $n$ is mulptiple of $4$

c) $a_n = \frac{1}{n} - 1$ when $n$ is even but not multiple of $4$

Which are the cluster points?
The solution is $A=\{-1,0,1\}$ but I don't understand why.

*My solution:*

a) $a_n = \frac{n+2+1}{n^2+n+1} = \frac{1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n}}{n+1+\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow 0$

b) $ \frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{sinn}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} ... \rightarrow 0$

c) $ a_n = \frac{1}{n} - 1 \rightarrow -1$

So, $A = \{-1,0 \}$

How did they find the cluster point $1$ ?

Comment: The subsequence c is $a_n = 1/n - n$ or $a_n = 1/n - 1$ like in your solution?

Comment: I edited it. Thank you

Comment: The subsequence c converges to -1. So, why -1 isn't a cluster point ?

Comment: Sorry, is 1 instead of -1

Comment: Ohh ok !! I have the same opinion about this. It is an exercise of a book that gives this solution. I mean $A = \{-1,0,1\} $

Comment: I'd almost guarantee that a) is a typo, and should have been $$\frac {n^2 +1}{n^2+n+1}$$This explains why $A$ includes $1$, and also why the numerator added $2$ and $1$ instead of $3$.

Comment: Maybe, the book has this mistake. Thank you !